# Pseudocode for a noising scheme

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

I am trying to recreate the code for a paper. The paper  describes a noising scheme like the following. $z = f(x) +S(x) \cdot \epsilon$

Where $\epsilon$ is the noise we call echo noise. It is because in the limiting case, the distribution of $z$ and $\epsilon$ should be same. That is if we have a dataset $\{x_0, x_1, \dotsc,x_i,.....,x_N\}$, then in the limiting case $\epsilon$ should be the following:

$\epsilon = f(x_0) + S(x_0)f(x_1) + S(x_0)S(x_1)f(x_2) + \dotsc$

Where $f$ and $S$ are functions of $x$.

Now I had created a pseudocode like this:

```python
epsilon = 0
S_prod = I (identity)
for i in (1,N):
    epsilon = epsilon + S_prod*f(x_i)
    S_prod = S_prod*S(x_i)
    z = f(x_0) + S(x_0)*S(x_0)*epsilon
end for
```

However there is a problem. In the limiting case $z$ becomes equal to $f(x_0) + S(x_0)f(x_1) + S(x_0)S(x_1)f(x_2) + S(x_0)S(x_1)S(x_2)f(x_3) + \dotsc$

Whereas $\epsilon$ would be $f(x_1) + S(x_1)f(x_2) + S(x_1)S(x_2)f(x_3)+ \dotsc$

So you see there is a mismatch. Could you help me design the perfect pseudocode ?

Comment: I did not get how you arrived at this: "$\epsilon = f(x_0) + S(x_0)f(x_1) + S(x_0)S(x_1)f(x_2) + \dotsc$". Could you please elaborate.